# How to convert to concrete types residing in external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, json-deserialization, converters

I have one assembly of POCO classes which I used as deserialization type for json text. Now I need to split the types across assemblies. I can directly add the reference but adding new assemblies would force me to recompile everytime, Is it possible to do this with configuration, What could be best way to achieve this?
The code written in same assembly works as expected, I need a way to distribute the classes in different assembly based on components. Can somebody suggest a way do this by configuration?

Comment: `using the.namespace.of.your.assembly;` (and of course, add a refrence to that dll in your project)

Comment: @Cid This was my bad, I have edited the question, I want this to be done with configuration if possible(dont know if Unity can help here), because using reference would lead to recompilation everytime.